# Hide category name but show posts

Tags: categories

I’m looking for a way to hide a specific category title (**not all but just one specific category title**) from being displayed on the **home page, archives, and search results** but still show the posts tagged under the category.

Is it possible to do it via CSS or functions hook?

Keep in mind that I want to hide the category title (not the posts under the category. Just the title) from being displayed on home page, archives, and search results.

However, the category name should be displayed on posts.

Comment: How are these categories being shown? I don't believe it's possible to write a one size fits all answer given that there are so many ways a category might be shown or listed, more information is needed

Comment: Can you share your current code? As another user commented, the answer to this question will depend on a lot of things, such as whether the listing is currently displayed by your theme, or by your widgets, etc. In general, you may be able to modify the function that's currently being called, and exclude the category title from the display if it matches the category ID you wish to exclude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfect. Note that `137` is the `category ID` that I wish to hide and `.home` is the page where I don't want it to be displayed

```
.home .entry-category-item-137 {
    display: none;
}
```